# “Out of” or “Outside” the box

Tags: grammar, adjectives, nouns, adverbs, creative-writing

For composition reasons and how it sound I would like to create a design called “creativity out of the box” but Im not sure if is correct or should be “outside”. Which one is correct?

Comment: Do you consider the more common one to be 'correct'? It might help to google both versions of your phrase to see which is standard.

Comment: "out" is usually used for motion, as in "go out of the house". "outside" is usually used for position, as in "he is outside the house".

Comment: What do you mean by "correct," exactly? Are you asking how people would understand it?

Answer (score 0):

“Out of the box” and “outside [of] the box” have sharply different meanings in typical, generally informal, use.

The first means ready for use without alteration, customization, or assembly, whereas the second implies creativity and is often used in the phrase “thinking outside the box.”  In both, what’s in the box is more or less standard, expected, typical.

See this [blog](https://blog.authenticjourneys.info/2018/03/what-does-out-of-the-box-mean.html)

Comment: [Even in AmE,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=think+out+of+the+box%2Cthink+outside+of+the+box&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=20) ***think out of the box*** is still slightly more common than ***think outside of the box***, and that's [even more true of BrE.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=think+out+of+the+box%2Cthink+outside+of+the+box&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=20) There are *some* usage differences (things *work straight **out** of the box*, never ***outside** of the box*). But ***thinking*** isn't one.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Note that "think outside the box," without the "of," is [much more common than either of those.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=think+out+of+the+box%2Cthink+outside+of+the+box%2Cthink+outside+the+box&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=20)

Comment: @alphabet: Yeah - I suppose ***-side*** acts a bit like a "built-in preposition" (cf ***beside***). So it's much more natural as a "prepositionless" usage: *I waited outside the door* is fine, but *I waited out the door* isn't.